# find the radius of convergence of a series that is not a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n = 0} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)^2 + |z|^2}$$

As mentioned in the title, how to find the radius of convergence?

In my opinion, $|z| \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z|^2$ is giving a real number, hence we can fix $|z|^2$ regardlessly. But then again, this is not a power series?

Comment: The series converges for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Does it converge uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. One way to see this is to note that
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n + 1)^2} = \frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{n + 1} - \frac{1\sqrt{n}}{(n + 1)^2} = a(n) - b(n).$$
You can use the comparison test with
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}, \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
to conclude that $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ converge, hence your series converges for $z = 0$. It follows by the comparison test that your series converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} }{(n + 1)^{2} + |z|^{2}} & \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} }{(n + 1)^{2}} \\
& \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} }{n^{2}} \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{-3/2} \\
& < \infty .
\end{align*}
So we have convergence for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and in fact the sum decreases as $|z| \to \infty$.

Comment: Yoy could even add that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{-3/2}=\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\approx 2.61238$. Cheers.